# Falling factorial summands

Tags: combinatorics, factorial, binomial-theorem

Representing the summand as a falling factorial Compute the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}=\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}$

$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}=\sum_{k=1}^n(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2})$

$(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4})+\ldots +(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2})$

$=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+2}=\frac{n}{2(n+2)}$

Comment: You just broke it into parts. That is not the sum

Comment: @Daniel This is a good hint.

Comment: @kmitov Yeah I know how to do this. I was wondering how to do it using the falling factorial? An example question is --- > http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210994/infinite-series-using-falling-factorials?rq=1